# Python remove blanks within a txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I wish to remove all empty spaces in a txt file

```
with open('helosystem1.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read().replace(' ', '')

with open('helosystem1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

has no effect, however if I run

```
tr -d '[:blank:]' <helosystem1.txt > helosystem1.csv
```

from the command line works perfectly. Why can't I do it in Python?

Comment: Are you aware of that your python program is writing to *same* file and the command line version is writing to a `.csv` file?

Comment: The top code works so I assume there's an issue with either calling the function to perform the action, you write the file again after this code, or there's an issue with the file somewhere. Is there any other code that follows it, how are you calling it, and is the file in the same directory?

Comment: there is no other code it makes no difference if i write to the same file or not and what is strange 
with open('helosystem1.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read().replace(' ,', '.') that works
 
 if i replace the empty space with a "," "." the script works

its as if the python cant read the empty spaces? within the txt file